# c++ - use asm in functions with just bytes instead of instruction name

Tags: c++, assembly, byte, instructions

Is there a way to write assembly instructions just by using its corresponding bytes. Something like this is what I'm thinking:

```
__asm {
 0x7D8802A6
 0x9181FFF8
}
```

instead of something like:

```
__asm {
 stw       r12, -8(r1)
}
```

Comment: What compiler? And why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm going to assume this is `armcc` or armkeil given the instruction set and the `__asm {` directive?

Comment: [__emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253948(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This will be highly compiler-dependent.  GCC's inline assembly syntax will accommodate anything the assembler is OK with, e.g.

```
__asm__(".word 0x7D8802A6, 0x9181FFF8")
```

I am not familiar with whichever compiler has the `__asm { ... }` syntax you refer to.